# TransactionManagementError “Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK" while making migrations in Django

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

When I make the migrations using `python manage.py migrate manage`  (yes it's Django 1.8 and I can't change it :/), the migrations (every single one I tested) always fail with the same error :

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

[image]

Here is the code from the migration file :

```py
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Check expiry keys in Organization
        for org in Organization.objects.all():
            self.checkExpiryDate(org)
        # Check expiry keys in UserProfileRoleInOrganization
        for uprio in UserProfileRoleInOrganization.objects.all():
            self.checkExpiryDate(uprio)

    def checkExpiryDate(self, entity):
        # Check if expiry_date is consistent with apikey and fix it if necessary
        if not entity.date_has_changed:
            return
        date_in_key = entity.getExpiryDateInKey()
        if not date_in_key:
            return
        y = int(date_in_key[:4])
        m = int(date_in_key[4:-2])
        d = int(date_in_key[-2:])
        entity.expiry_date = datetime.datetime(y,m,d)
        entity.save()

    def backwards(self, orm):
        pass
```

I've seen some answers to other similar questions but no, I don't have any @commit.... decorator in my code.

May somebody help me please ?

Comment: What is `SchemaMigration`?

Comment: How did you declare Organization and UserProfileRoleInOrganization declared in the data migration ?

Comment: @nima It's a South Model from south.v2 but I checked, it herits from BaseMigration but is hardly empty

Comment: @MarioOrlandi I simply made two "import" statements if that's what you're asking for. I know they're working fine

Comment: I'll reply with a proper answer, to have some formatting available ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the migrations folder and re run migrations
./manage.py makemigrations app
./manage.py migrate

or

You also can fake the migrations and reset it

Comment: Thank you very much, I did the first thing but it didn't work but then I faked them and it kinda worked for me. I wouldn't say it's the proper thing to do to solve this problem but it helps bypassing it. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

In a data migration, you should avoid importing the Model directly, since the "actual" Model might be inconsistent with previous migrations.

So, for example, use:

```
# We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
# version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
Person = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Person')
```

instead of

```
from yourappname.models import Person
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

This at least with recent versions of Django; I don't remember exactly how to cope with this with South

You might also try to add this option to the DATABASES['default'] definition:

```
'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,}
```

since with Django 1.8 the default for autocommit was False (probably); sometimes, this helps in receiving the proper db exception.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I'll use the proper way to import models on DataMigrations now. I'm sure what you're telling me is working on recent versions of Django, but I tested the options and the imports and none of them helped me to get better results on Django 1.8. But thank you for the help and for now, you'll get the bounty :)

Comment: Hello @Arlien, no intention at all to force you in using a newer version of Django: I know sometimes this is not viable ;) I just wanted to clarify that my suggestion might require some adaptations with South